# How to simplify this to radicals?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The result of

```
max = Maximize[{x*y + y*z + z*t + t*x,  x*y*z*t == 4 && 
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + t^2 == 10 && {x, y, z, t} > 0}, {x, y, z, t}]
```

> `{Sqrt[82], {x ->  4/(Root[{-82 + #^2 &, 64 - 125 #2^2 + 25 #2^4 &,  160000 + 160000 # #2 #3 + 4920000 #2^2 #3^2 -  100000 #2^4 #3^2 + 20000 #2^6 #3^2 + 860000 # #2^3 #3^3 -  50000 # #2^5 #3^3 + 5000 # #2^7 #3^3 - 335872 #3^4 +  1212000 #2^2 #3^4 + 4318850 #2^4 #3^4 - 8192 # #2 #3^5 -  18000 # #2^3 #3^5 + 187350 # #2^5 #3^5 + 40960 #3^6 -  148192 #2^2 #3^6 - 292250 #2^4 #3^6 + 372350 #2^6 #3^6 +  5000 # #2^3 #3^7 - 12500 # #2^5 #3^7 + 5000 # #2^7 #3^7 -  20480 #3^8 + 80000 #2^2 #3^8 - 42875 #2^4 #3^8 +  12500 #2^6 #3^8 + 1250 # #2^5 #3^9 + 1250 #2^6 #3^10 &}, {1, 3, 2}] Root[{-82 + #^2 &, 64 - 125 #2^2 + 25 #2^4 &,  160000 + 160000 # #2 #3 + 4920000 #2^2 #3^2 -  100000 #2^4 #3^2 + 20000 #2^6 #3^2 + 860000 # #2^3 #3^3 -  50000 # #2^5 #3^3 + 5000 # #2^7 #3^3 - 335872 #3^4 +  1212000 #2^2 #3^4 + 4318850 #2^4 #3^4 - 8192 # #2 #3^5 -  18000 # #2^3 #3^5 + 187350 # #2^5 #3^5 + 40960 #3^6 -  148192 #2^2 #3^6 - 292250 #2^4 #3^6 + 372350 #2^6 #3^6 +  5000 # #2^3 #3^7 - 12500 # #2^5 #3^7 + 5000 # #2^7 #3^7 -  20480 #3^8 + 80000 #2^2 #3^8 - 42875 #2^4 #3^8 +  12500 #2^6 #3^8 + 1250 # #2^5 #3^9 + 1250 #2^6 #3^10 &,  4 #2 + 4 #4 + # #2 #3 #4 + #2^2 #3^2 #4 + #2 #3^2 #4^2 &}, {1, 3, 2, 2}] Root[64 - 125 #^2 + 25 #^4 &, 3, 0]),  y -> Root[64 - 125 #^2 + 25 #^4 &, 3, 0],  z -> Root[{-82 + #^2 &, 64 - 125 #2^2 + 25 #2^4 &,  160000 + 160000 # #2 #3 + 4920000 #2^2 #3^2 - 100000 #2^4 #3^2 +  20000 #2^6 #3^2 + 860000 # #2^3 #3^3 - 50000 # #2^5 #3^3 +  5000 # #2^7 #3^3 - 335872 #3^4 + 1212000 #2^2 #3^4 +  4318850 #2^4 #3^4 - 8192 # #2 #3^5 - 18000 # #2^3 #3^5 +  187350 # #2^5 #3^5 + 40960 #3^6 - 148192 #2^2 #3^6 -  292250 #2^4 #3^6 + 372350 #2^6 #3^6 + 5000 # #2^3 #3^7 -  12500 # #2^5 #3^7 + 5000 # #2^7 #3^7 - 20480 #3^8 +  80000 #2^2 #3^8 - 42875 #2^4 #3^8 + 12500 #2^6 #3^8 +  1250 # #2^5 #3^9 + 1250 #2^6 #3^10 &}, {1, 3, 2}],  t -> Root[{-82 + #^2 &, 64 - 125 #2^2 + 25 #2^4 &,  160000 + 160000 # #2 #3 + 4920000 #2^2 #3^2 - 100000 #2^4 #3^2 +  20000 #2^6 #3^2 + 860000 # #2^3 #3^3 - 50000 # #2^5 #3^3 +  5000 # #2^7 #3^3 - 335872 #3^4 + 1212000 #2^2 #3^4 +  4318850 #2^4 #3^4 - 8192 # #2 #3^5 - 18000 # #2^3 #3^5 +  187350 # #2^5 #3^5 + 40960 #3^6 - 148192 #2^2 #3^6 -  292250 #2^4 #3^6 + 372350 #2^6 #3^6 + 5000 # #2^3 #3^7 -  12500 # #2^5 #3^7 + 5000 # #2^7 #3^7 - 20480 #3^8 +  80000 #2^2 #3^8 - 42875 #2^4 #3^8 + 12500 #2^6 #3^8 +  1250 # #2^5 #3^9 + 1250 #2^6 #3^10 &,  4 #2 + 4 #4 + # #2 #3 #4 + #2^2 #3^2 #4 + #2 #3^2 #4^2 &}, {1, 3, 2, 2}]}}`

in version 13.1 on Windows 10 is a serious achievement of Mathematica and its developers.

However, there is a room to improve here. As I know it, an optimal solution can be written as $$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}} ,z=\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}, y=\sqrt{\dfrac{25- 3\sqrt {41}}{10}},t=\sqrt{\dfrac{25+ 3\sqrt {41}}{10}} $$

and

```
N[max]
```

> `{9.05539, {x -> 1.58114, y -> 0.760962, z -> 1.58114, t -> 2.1026}}`

confirms it. The question arises: how to simplify the result of `max` to radicals (`RootApproximant` is not taken into consideration)? Here is my attempt

```
FullSimplify[max[[2, 2]]]
```

> $$y\to \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}-\frac{3 \sqrt{41}}{10}} $$

Unfortunately,

```
FullSimplify[max[[2, 3]]]
```

is running without any response for a coon's age.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
max = Maximize[{x*y + y*z + z*t + t*x, 
   x*y*z*t == 4 && 
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + t^2 == 10 && {x, y, z, t} > 0}, {x, y, z, t}]

vars = Last@max

RootReduce /@ vars // ToRadicals
```

$$\left\{x\to \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}},y\to \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(25-3 \sqrt{41}\right)},z\to \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}},t\to \sqrt{\frac{3 \sqrt{41}}{10}+\frac{5}{2}}\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

As shown by `Syed`

```
max1 = Maximize[{x*y + y*z + z*t + t*x, 
     x*y*z*t == 4 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + t^2 == 10 && {x, y, z, t} > 0}, 
     {x, y, z, t}] // RootReduce // ToRadicals

(* {Sqrt[82], {x -> Sqrt[5/2], y -> Sqrt[1/10 (25 - 3 Sqrt[41])], 
   z -> Sqrt[5/2], t -> Sqrt[5/2 + (3 Sqrt[41])/10]}} *)
```

Use [`ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RadicalDenest/) to simplify further

```
max2 = max1 /. x_?NumericQ :> ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"][x] // Quiet

(* {Sqrt[82], {x -> Sqrt[5/2], y -> (-3 + Sqrt[41])/(2 Sqrt[5]), 
  z -> Sqrt[5/2], t -> (3 + Sqrt[41])/(2 Sqrt[5])}} *)
```

Verifying the equivalence,

```
({x, y, z, t} /. max1[[2]]) == ({x, y, z, t} /. max2[[2]]) // Simplify

(* True *)
```